# UISearchBar is not filtering custom cell images from UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to filter a TableView with a search bar. The TableView has a custom prototype cell that has an Imageview and a label so it can be called. The label is hidden underneath the image.

I have two arrays with 94 items in each. It works fine when nothing is searched for. The tableview displays the images/cell in perfect order.

When I search for something- the results always come back with the appropriate number of cells. However, the images themselves are not filtered. This means that no matter what cells are filtered by label, the images will always be the same.

Is this a problem with my UISearchBar code?

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {    
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
       isFiltered = NO;    
     }    else    {
       isFiltered = YES;
       filteredHeroes = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

       for (NSString *str in totalHeroData)    {

           NSRange heroRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

           if (heroRange.location != NSNotFound) {
               [filteredHeroes addObject:str];

           }
       }    }    [self.HeroTableView reloadData]; }
```

I would be happy to provide any other resources. Remember, I have two 94-item arrays. If I need to link them I would like to know how to do that as well.

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is the Cellforrowatindexpath method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath 
*)indexPath {    
       static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"heroTableCell";
       HeroTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
       if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[HeroTableViewCell alloc]
               initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
               reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];    
       }
       // Configure the cell...
       cell.textLabel.text = [self.heroNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];            
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.heroImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

       return cell; 
   }
```

Thanks for asking- let me know what you think :)
I've spent about 10 hours searching the web :S

Comment: You need to post your cellforrowatindexpath method.

Comment: Added! the cellforrowatindexpath method :)

Comment: In searchBar:textDidChange: you are filtering data in filteredHeroes array and in cellForRowAtIndexPath you are using heroNames & heroImages. Can you tell how you are relating these?

Comment: @Nick, You have filtered the `filteredHeroes` and not `heroNames` and `heroImages` arrays. You need to filter that as well.

Answer (score 0):

you should use one nsmutuable array and add nsdictionary which contains one key imagename and one key Name as string

[filteredHeroes addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:name,@"Name",ImageName,@"Image", nil]];
use same filteredHeroes in cellForRowAtIndexPath and filter the same array using key Name and reload TableData and done.